# TYPO3.Surf installation within TYPO3 CMS

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-surf

Just tried to install TYPO3 Surf at a TYPO3 CMS 7.6.10 Installation, but it didn't work.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3_src-7.6.10>composer require typo3/surf=dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for typo3/surf dev-master -> satisfiable by typo3/surf[dev-master].
    - typo3/surf dev-master requires symfony/console ^2.8|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 3):

Without actually using surf currently, check out the latest betas, as a phar file is now used. So you don't need any composer installation and you won't run into those troubles you have right now.

Check out https://github.com/TYPO3/Surf/releases

Comment: I am using Windows, how can I execute the phar file

Comment: This should work out same as for the composer phar file https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Answer (score 2):

At the moment only works with TYPO3 CMS 8 and newer.

The TYPO3 CMS 7 uses a old version of `symfony/console`.

```
    {
      "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "composer",
          "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
        }
      ],
      "name": "markussom/creativeworkspace",
      "require": {
        "typo3/cms": "8.3.1 as 7.6.10",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-rsaauth": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-rtehtmlarea": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^8.3",
        "typo3-ter/news": "^5.0.0",
        "typo3-ter/realurl": "^2.0.14",
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^3.3.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "package-states": [
          "./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "folder-structure": [
          "./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "@package-states",
          "@folder-structure"
        ]
      },
      "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
          "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
          "web-dir": "Web"
        },
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
          "install-binary": false
        }
      }
      "require-dev": {
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^8.3",
        "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "^8.3",
        "TYPO3/Surf": "dev-master"
      },
      "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Meanwhile TYPO3 7.6.x dependencies have been updated to make it possible to install surf along with TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of keeping giving an alternative in more recent times since the question was asked, there are a number of people starting to move to Docker and the easiest way I know how to do that is for TYPO3 is with DDEV, which is open source. Currently the opensource version for DDEV Live is not available yet but we're using DDEV Local for all local development and live is supposed to be showing up soon or so they've said. There's also DDEV Live available directly from DRUD which would be a managed solution and it sound like it's pretty robust setup though I haven't personally used it yet.

- https://www.drud.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZVMPoI9SIk